# convert selected item back to custom data type, winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

listview is populated with list of custom type datatype. Now I want to convert selected row from listview back to the custom data type, I tried this

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var selected = (CustomDataType)listview1.SelectedItems[0];
}
```

This doesn't work. Reason for this is that I need access to `CustomDataType` to decrease totalValue using value from this CustomDataType before deleting.

Again, how to convert selected item from `listview` to the `CustomDataType`?

Update:
CustomType is ArticleDetails which has `Article` and `int Quantity` properties.
and I want to access to `Article.Price` property before delete that selected item from the listview because I want to decrease `totalPrice` value.

Update2

listview is populated like this

```
listview1.Columns.Add("Col1");
listview1.Columns.Add("Col2");
foreach(ArticleDetails ad in myCollection)
{
   var row = new ListViewItem(ad.Article.Name);
   row.SubItems.Add(ad.Article.Price);
}
listVuew1.View = View.Details;
```

Comment: Try adding .value at the end.

Comment: Could you show us the code to `populate your listview`?

Comment: @KingKong added as you asked

Comment: i like a well defined question like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
listview1.Columns.Add("Col1");
listview1.Columns.Add("Col2");
foreach(ArticleDetails ad in myCollection)
{
   var row = new ListViewItem(ad.Article.Name);
   row.Tag = ad; // You can use this to store your object
   row.SubItems.Add(ad.Article.Price);
}
listview1.View = View.Details;


private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var selected = (CustomDataType)listview1.SelectedItems[0].Tag;
}
```

Comment: Where can you find the `Value` property of a `ListViewItem`?

Comment: Cannot find Value property.

Comment: @panjo, Sorry I thought you were talking about WebForms, See Update.

Answer (score 1):

i think yogi answer should be explained:
when you are doing the convert `(CustomDataType)x`, if x is null or not a `CustomDataType` then you'll get exception.

when you do `x as CustomDataType`, if x is null or not a `CustomDataType` you'll just get null, and then you check `if(selected != null)` to see if conversion passed.

however, you should always check

```
listview1.SelectedItems != null && listview1.SelectedItems.Count > 0
```